# Should I SSL encrypt traffic between two AWS AZ/region?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I know theoretically the answer is of course "yes". But is there real valid reason to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traffic between two EC2 regions may travel over public networks, so it should be encrypted if it is not public data.

Traffic between two EC2 availability zones in the same region is kept within Amazon's private network and they protect it against being seen by other customers.  However, Amazon still recommends you encrypt network traffic between EC2 instances if you consider it sensitive.

Comment: Are you able to cite where that recomendation comes from?